# Automatically place imported Megascans materials into assets-library

Tags: materials, asset-browser, asset

is there a way of automatically placing imported Megascans materials into your Blender asset-library? Or is there any similar way of listing them visually in a list across Blend files, without having to make each material into an asset?

Comment: Never heard of Megascans, but a quick Google shows [this](https://help.quixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007480698-User-Guide-Megascans-Plugin-for-Blender) Blender addon for it.